# What does dragging a file over another file and releasing do exactly?

Tags: windows, python, java, drag-and-drop

I've had an idea of writing a program that's *too easy to use*. It would require a user to drag an image file onto the program's file (`.py` or `.jar`), then process the image and save it at the program's location.

I'm very unsure of how this actually works, but I believe it's basically the same as right-clicking the image and going to the `open with` section.

[Opening a text file with another file through drag and drop (GIF)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84j25.gif)

In the example, what I believe might be happening is that `textfile.txt` is being passed to Notepad++ as arguments, but what type of argument could this be and how would one access it through python / java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it will call the program with the filename path of the dragged file as argument.

eg: dragging `image.jpg` into `script.py`
is equivalent to typing (command line):
`script.py "image.jpg"`

(Probably full paths are involved, etc...)

you may test it with the following python script:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Should've been able to think of this myself, but thank you, this worked nicely. `sys.argv` returns the file location which I can then just use to read data from whichever file was dragged onto the script.